# Difficulty with putting an png image on a button on html

Tags: html

I write something like this:

```
<input id="btn1" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" type="image" src="images/refresh.png" onclick="refresh()"/>
```

But when I run it, it can't show the image. It show a 'x' only. Do you guys know why?
My image size is 32x32px.

Comment: How about changing from input to <img> and using an onClick event handler?

Comment: Is your image getting loaded, did you check if your path is correct. You can check in chrome console if it is giving 404 error while loading the image.

Comment: Do you get a 404 for that image in your browser debugger?

Comment: What do you mean 404? My browser just show a 'x' for the image if i use ie.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: My respond code for that image is 200. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong path and your image is not located at `images/refresh.png` as it works fine when I use your markup with another image. Did you to use `/` at the start like this `/images/refresh.png`?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDGP8/2/)

```
<input id="btn1" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" type="image" src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png" onclick="refresh()"/>
```

---

FYI alternative ways to do this are to either apply the image using CSS or use a `<button>` tag combined with an `<img>`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDGP8/1/)

```
<input id="btn1" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; background-image:url(https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png);" type="button" />
<button>
    <img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png" style="width:32px;height:32px;" />
</button>
```