# Webpack src replacement doesn't work in <input> elements?

Tags: html, angular, webpack

I have an angular project using webpack where I'm trying to use an input element as a clickable image, since I need the 'disabled' functionality, like so:

`<li> <input src="../../resources/settings.png" type="image" /> </li>`

however, no matter what I do, I always get a 404 error in the browser since it appears that webpack doesn't correctly replace the path:

[image]

it does, however, work if I use just an img element instead:

`<li> <img src="../../resources/settings.png" /> </li>`

[image]

Why exactly, is it that webpack appears not to properly replace the src attribute of an input element, but does so correctly with the img element (and many others that I use elsewhere in the project)?

UPDATE:
I haven't been able to find a solution to the above issue, but as a workaround I just ended up not using the url-loader plugin to deal with images and instead used the CopyWebpackPlugin to copy my entire assets folder to the output folder of the webpack build step.

If anyone comes up with a solution to the posted question, I'm still interested.

Comment: Is it really version 2 of Angular, or from Angular 2 you mean a version of Angular which is not "1"

Comment: It's the version that _isn't_ AngularJS. The actual version according to NPM is "4.2.5"

Comment: Why don't you put your image (`settings.png`) into assets directory?

Then write the following address:
`/assets/images/settings.png`

Comment: If you don't find the solution, you can use one of the workarounds suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16227943/1009922).

Comment: @M98 I'm not using angular-cli as part of my project, so using the "assets" directory isn't a possibility.